# Sass loop @import, a.scss need class on b.scss, b.scss need class on a.scss

Tags: css, loops, import, sass, less

I am trying to organize my .css files in sections, and I need to access from any file to any class in the file group.
In Less, I have no problem creating a main file with imports of all files, and each file imports the main file, but in Sass I receive a loop error @import.

```
    // main.scss

    @import "_a.scss", "_b.scss";

    // _a.scss

    @import "main.scss";
    $colorA: #ff0000;
    .classA
    {
        color: $colorB;
    }


    // _b.scss

    @import "main.scss";
    $colorB: #b6ff00;
    .classB
    {
        color: $colorA;
    }
// ERROR
```

This code works in Less, but not in Sass.

How can I access _a.scss from _b.scss and _b.scss from _a.scss?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the scss files not preceding with **_ underscore**.
Because scss file preceding with _ underscore reefers to partials and the search path for a.scss and _a.scss(partial) differs

Comment: According to the documentation and my tests, when there is no file with the same name without underscore _, Sass understands that _a.scss is equal to a.scss but does not generate the .css. I get the error with all possible varieties of names. I have also tried to reference the files independently.
   
    `// a.scss
    @import "b.scss";

    // b.scss
    @import "c.scss";

    // c.scss
    @import "a.scss";`
    
The final result is always the same, a.scss imports b.scss, b.scss import c.scss, and finally c.scss re-imports a.scss

Answer (score 0):

```
@import a;

@import b;

@import main;
```

You are using a and b as partials and thats fine. No need for "" or comma. Put them on separate lines. What is the name of the file you are importing these into? If it is main, dont import it. If main is a separate scss file, make it a partial and import it

I suggest you look up some tutorials on youtube on using SMACSS. It works very good for organizing SASS files into sections